# How to accept the concurrent request in sockets using C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, server, concurrency

Suppose I have five machines (`A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, and `B`), `A1-4` are servers where each of them is listening the requests from clients such as `B`. Now I just have one client `B`.

First, I concurrently sent data from `B` to `A1-4` using the `socket` apis, `A1-4` will parallelly process the data. Then they will send the result data to `B`.

```
// Servers: 
// A1: 192.168.1.101:10001
// A2: 192.168.1.102:10001
// A3: 192.168.1.103:10001
// A4: 192.168.1.104:10001

// Client:
// B: 192.168.1.100
```

First, connect to the servers `A1-4` from `B` and send data:

```
SOCKET sockets[4];
for i in range(4):
    sockets[i] = socket(servers[i], ...)
    connect(sockets[i], ...)

char bufdata[bufsize];
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for i in range(4):
    std::thread t(send_data_and_receive_result, sockets[i], bufdata, ...)
    threads.push_back(t)
for i in range(4):
    if (threads[i].joinable())
        threads[i].join()
```

Then, in `A1-4`, they will parallel process the data, for example, in each of them:

```
sock = socket(...)
bind(sock, port=10001, ...)
listen(sock, ...)
while(1) {
    select(...)
    for (int i = 0; i < maxfd; i++) {
        SOCKET s = rread.fd_array[i];
        if (s == sock) {
            new_client = accept(sock, ...)
            FD_SET(new_client, ...)
        } else {
            char recvbuf[bufsize];
            recv(s, recvbuf, ...)
            
            char resultbuf[bufsize];
            process_data(recvbuf, resultbuf);

            // send the resultbuf back to `B` using `s`
            // Error here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            // `B` cannot obtain the data
            send(s, resultbuf, ...)
        }
    }
}
```

In this way, it is expected that the `resultbuf` data will be received in each of the thread of `B`, i.e., it is expect that in `send_data_and_receive_result` function, after sending the data, the thread will using the same socket object to obtain the result data from each of the server (`A1-4`). But no data is received. I am not sure where the problem is.

After that, I have tried another method. I also open a new server thread (the listensing port is `10000`) in `B` where it can listen the socket requests from other clients such as `A1-4`. The main logic is similar to that described above. Instead using `s` in `send(s, resultbuf, ...)`, I also create a new socket request in each of `A1-4` to build connection from `A1-4` to `B`:

```
// In `B`, the server is listening in port 10000
// In the `send(s, resultbuf, ...)` of `A1-4`
// they will be replaced with the following:
new_socket = socket(B_server_information, port=10000)
connect(new_socket, ...)
send(new_socket, resultbuf, ...)  // send the resultbuf data in a new socket object
```

In this trial, it seems the `A1-4` will concurrently connect to the `B` in the same port of 10000. In each of `A1-4`, the log information will show the connection is successfully built, and the `resultbuf` is all sent to `B`. But `B` will exit unexpectedly. I am not sure where the problem is.

I am not sure if I have made myself clear on my question. I expect that the `resultbuf` data will be sent back to `B` using the same socket who is connecting it. But no luck. So I tried the latter method, but still no luck.

So if convenient, could you please give some advice? Thanks.

**UPDATED**

The `send_data_and_receive_result` function is like this:

```
void send_data_and_receive_result(SOCKET sock, char* bufdata, int bufsize) {
    // send data from `B` to servers `A1-4` using the socket object `sock`
    send(sock, bufdata, bufsize, ...)


    std::cout << "begin receiving result data from the server\n"
    char recvbuf[2048];
    char *resultbuf = new char[100000000];
    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    size_t all_bytes_read = 0;

    int total_size = 0;
    while(1) {
        while((bytes_read = recv(sock, recvbuf, 2048)) > 0) {
            if (total_size == 0) {
                total_size = atoi(recvbuf); // in the first recv, I obtain how much data will be sent in this socket
            }

            // copy the current received buf data to the final buf
            memcpy(resultbuf + all_bytes_read, recvbuf, bytes_read);
         
            all_bytes_read += bytes_read;
        }

        if (total_size == all_bytes_read) {// received the data
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "result data is received";
    // save the result data
    ...
    delete[]  resultbuf; resultbuf = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `send_data_and_receive_result`?

Comment: Please show a [mre] of the actual code you are using, what you've posted looks like some weird mash up of c++ and python

Comment: Hi @kiner_shah, I have updated my question, please help check that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AlanBirtles, thanks very much for your kind suggestion! Currently the code in my project is truly in a mess. So I just describe the problem in the question. I am not familiar with the socket programming. Also I am not sure if I correctly set the socket related configurations.

Comment: I think you need to do some debugging either using a debugger or placing print statements in different places. One suggestion: Always reset the receive buffer before `recv`, use `memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));`.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yeah, thanks very much for your kind suggestion. I'll try that.